# How to cd to $RECYCLE.BIN?

Tags: dual-boot, lxterminal

I made a dualboot between Windows 8.1 and Lubuntu 14.04.
I tried access the Lubuntu files with a ext2/3/4 driver for Windows. But when I went back for Lubuntu, there are in `/` a folder named `$RECYCLE.BIN`.
Now I am trying to enter via terminal, but is shows:

```
yuri@yuri-Aspire-E1-572:/$ cd "$RECYCLE.BIN"
bash: cd: .BIN: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

It means that `cd` does not find `.BIN`.
I only can access through a graphical file manager.

So, how to cd to a folder with name starting with "`$`"?

Comment: `cd *RECYCLE*` seems to work.

Comment: You can use `cd "\$RECYCLE.BIN"/
`

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways:

```
cd '$RECYCLE.BIN'
cd \$RECYCLE.BIN
```

See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/163515) for a discussion of escaping.